# How to integrate test this method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, integration-testing

Hi I am writing integration tests.

My method is

```
public IList<string> GetUsersRecursively(string groupName)
    {
        using (var context = GetPrincipalContext())
        {
            using (var group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, groupName))
            {
                using (var users = group.GetMembers(true))
                {
                    return (from user in users 
                            orderby user.SamAccountName
                            select user.SamAccountName
                            ).ToList();
                }; // recursively enumerate
            }
        }
        //          return results;
    }
```

And Test I have written is

```
    [Test]
    public void GetUsersRecursively()
    {
        // Arrange
        var target = this.provider;
        string groupName = "CAS_Branch_Manager";
        string expectedUsername = "test.branchmanager";

        // Act
        var result = this.provider.GetUsersRecursively(groupName);

        // Assert
        Assert.NotNull(result);
        CollectionAssert.Contains(result, expectedUsername);
    }
```

But by running it on resharper it shows error that

System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalServerDownException : The server could not be contacted.
  ----> System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapException : The LDAP server is unavailable.

Then to handle exception I have written as

```
            [Test]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(PrincipalServerDownException ))]
    public void GetUsersRecursively()
    {
        // Arrange
        var target = this.provider;
        string groupName = "CAS_Branch_Manager";
        string expectedUsername = "test.branchmanager";

        // Act
        var result = this.provider.GetUsersRecursively(groupName);

        // Assert
        Assert.NotNull(result);
        CollectionAssert.Contains(result, expectedUsername);
    }
```

But now PrincipalServerDownException showing error as cannot resolve symbol "PrincipalServerDownException". HOw to solve it ?

Comment: Inject a mock principal and use that instead of the real one.

Comment: do you want to write a unit test or an integration test? for a unit test the way to go is to wrap the `GroupPrincipal` so that you can mock it.

Comment: I just want to handle exception PrincipalServerDownException as expected exception but I am facing error thrown by resharper. How to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to add a reference to 'System.DirectoryServices' assembly in your test project.

Comment: yes i have added reference but still PrincipalServerDownException is showing error.

Comment: Actually its in the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement assembly.